# Missing Symbol during Runtime in Over-The-Air Programming Code

Tags: c, shell, air, symbols, contiki

I am currently working on developing over-the-air programming support on sky motes.  Attached are the files that I have so far.  I am basically trying to use the sky-shell-exec example to load my modified test-deluge.ce file onto the mote.  I then try to run the test-deluge file using the shell 'exec' command as done in the sky-shell-exec example.
The final goal is to load both the test-deluge.ce and hello-world.ce compiled files onto the mote and then be able to 'exec' my test-deluge.ce file which would then find the stored hello-world.ce file and do a deluge_disseminate on it.

The progression of command I am running are as follows:

```
1) sudo make TARGET=sky clean CLEAN=symbols.?
2) sudo make sky-shell-exec.sky TARGET=sky
3) sudo make sky-shell-exec.sky CORE=sky-shell-exec.sky TARGET=sky
4) sudo make sky-shell-exec.upload CORE=sky-shell-exec.sky
5) sudo make compile-test-deluge-executable
6) sudo make upload-test-deluge-executable
7) sudo make login 
8) ls (to see that the file made it)
9) exec test-deluge.ce
```

At this point I get a 'Symbol not found: deluge_disseminate' error

I believe the error is in the 'CORE=...' part of the make (in step 2 above).  I have inspected the symbols.c file that is filled out in step 2 of the above and indeed there is no symbol for deluge_disseminate or any of the deluge commands for that matter that I recall.

For experimentation I tried the following:

```
sudo make test-deluge.sky TARGET=sky
sudo make test-deluge.sky CORE=test-deluge.sky TARGET=sky
```

and I find that the symbols for deluge are there, but I can't proceed to properly make sky-shell-exec file since doing so erases the symbols table and writes a new one.

I feel like there must be a simple fix to this as I can run hello-world from the sky-shell-exec example directory after following the above steps (1-9).

Does anyone have an idea of how to go about this?

NOTE:  There may be a bug in my test-deluge.c where I try to open 'hello-world.sky' instead of 'hello-world.ce'...I wasn't really sure which one.  I haven't been able to test this yet because of the missing symbol issue explained above, but if anyone would be willing to shed light on this issue as well I would be very appreciative.

Thanks

**MAKEFILE**

```
CONTIKI = ../..
ifndef TARGET
TARGET=sky
endif

APPS = deluge serial-shell
all: blink sky-collect #rt-leds test-button test-cfs tcprudolph0
#all: $(CONTIKI_PROJECT)

%.tgz: %.ihex
    mkdir $(basename $<) ; \
    mv $< $(basename $<) ; \
    echo $(basename $<)/$(basename $<).ihex 600 > $(basename $<)/runfile ; \
    tar czf $@ $(basename $<)

%.class: %.java
    javac $(basename $<).java

viewrssi: ViewRSSI.class
    make login | java ViewRSSI

include $(CONTIKI)/Makefile.include

%.shell-upload: %.ce
    (echo; sleep 4; echo "~K"; sleep 4; \
     echo "dec64 | write $*.ce | null"; sleep 4; \
     ../../tools/base64-encode < $<; sleep 4; \
     echo ""; echo "~K"; echo "read $*.ce | size"; sleep 4) | make login

.PHONY: compile-test-deluge-executable upload-test-deluge-executable compile-hello-world-executable upload-test-deluge-executable 

compile-hello-world-executable: hello-world.ce
    echo Compiled Contiki executable: $<

upload-hello-world-executable: hello-world.shell-upload
    echo Uploaded Contiki executable: $<

compile-test-deluge-executable: test-deluge.ce
    echo Compiled Contiki executable: $<

upload-test-deluge-executable: test-deluge.shell-upload
    echo Uploaded Contiki executable: $<
```

**sky-shell-exec.c**

```
#include "contiki.h"
#include "shell.h"
#include "serial-shell.h"
#include "deluge.h"

#include "dev/watchdog.h"

#include "net/rime.h"
#include "dev/cc2420.h"
#include "dev/leds.h"
#include "dev/light.h"
#include "dev/sht11.h"
#include "dev/battery-sensor.h"

#include "lib/checkpoint.h"

#include "net/rime/timesynch.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int (*keep_1)(void) = deluge_disseminate;
int (*keep_2)(void) = node_id_burn;

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
PROCESS(sky_shell_process, "Sky Contiki shell");
AUTOSTART_PROCESSES(&sky_shell_process);
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
PROCESS_THREAD(sky_shell_process, ev, data)
{
 PROCESS_BEGIN();

 serial_shell_init();
 /*shell_blink_init();*/
 shell_file_init();
 shell_coffee_init();
 /*shell_ps_init();*/
 /*shell_reboot_init();*/
 /*shell_rime_init();*/
 /*shell_rime_netcmd_init();*/
 /*shell_rime_ping_init();*/
 /*shell_rime_debug_init();*/
 /*shell_rime_sniff_init();*/
 /*shell_sky_init();*/
 shell_text_init();
 /*shell_time_init();*/
 /*  shell_checkpoint_init();*/
 shell_exec_init();
 shell_base64_init();

 PROCESS_END();
}
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

**test-deluge.c**

```
#include "contiki.h"
#include "cfs/cfs.h"
#include "deluge.h"
#include "sys/node-id.h"
#include "loader/elfloader.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifndef SINK_ID
#define SINK_ID 1
#endif

#ifndef FILE_SIZE
#define FILE_SIZE 1000
#endif

PROCESS(deluge_test_process, "Deluge test process");
AUTOSTART_PROCESSES(&deluge_test_process);
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
PROCESS_THREAD(deluge_test_process, ev, data)
{
 static struct etimer et;

 node_id_burn(2);
 PROCESS_BEGIN();

 if(node_id == SINK_ID) {
   printf("Sink node: trying to transmit file.\n");
 } else {
   printf("Non-sink node: trying to recieve file.\n");
 }

 cfs_remove("hello-world.sky");
 int fd = cfs_open("hello-world.sky", CFS_WRITE | CFS_READ);
 if(fd < 0) {
   process_exit(NULL);
 }

#if 0
 if(cfs_seek(fd, FILE_SIZE, CFS_SEEK_SET) != FILE_SIZE) {
   printf("failed to seek to the end\n");
 }
#endif

 deluge_disseminate("hello-world.sky", node_id == SINK_ID);
 cfs_close(fd);

 etimer_set(&et, CLOCK_SECOND * 5);
 PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT_UNTIL(etimer_expired(&et));
 if(node_id != SINK_ID) {
   fd = cfs_open("hello-world.sky", CFS_READ);
   if(fd < 0) {
     printf("failed to open the test file\n");
   } else {
     printf("Start dynamic loading\n");
     int ret = elfloader_load(fd);
     printf("%d\n", ret); 

     cfs_close(fd);

     int i;
     switch(ret) {
case ELFLOADER_OK:
 for(i=0; elfloader_autostart_processes[i] != NULL; i++) {
   printf("exec: starting process %s. \n", 
  elfloader_autostart_processes[i]->name);
 }
 autostart_start(elfloader_autostart_processes);
         break;

default:
 printf("Unkown return code from ELF loader (internal bug)\n");
          break;
     } 
   }
 }
 etimer_reset(&et);

 PROCESS_END();
}
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

**hello-world.c**

```
#include "contiki.h"

#include <stdio.h> /* For printf() */
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
PROCESS(hello_world_process, "Hello world process");
AUTOSTART_PROCESSES(&hello_world_process);
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
PROCESS_THREAD(hello_world_process, ev, data)
{
 PROCESS_BEGIN();

 printf("Hello, world\n");

 PROCESS_END();
}
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

Answer (score 0):

So with great help from the contiki community I was able to gather the following solution:

"Hi,

The problem is that the build system of Contiki tries to "act smart"
and excludes symbols the application *apparently* does not need. So in
this case the deluge_disseminate function code is optimized away from
sky-shell-exec executable. Obviously, this conflicts with the basic
intuitions that the programmer has in case of over-the-air
programming.

To work around this issue, add a reference to deluge_disseminate in
sky-shell-exec code. For example, add this line (at global scope):
int (*keep)(void) = deluge_disseminate;

You can also try to tweak GCC linker options or use a custom linker script."

Using the same trick for node_id_burn as well, test-deluge.c runs.
The corrections have been made to the above code.
Hopefully this helps anyone else out there who may be struggling with OTA code in Contiki.